# iPhone simulator for Windows

Tags: windows, webkit, ios-simulator

I would like an iPhone simulator for Windows. Something similar to this one here:

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/38-basics-tips-on-designing-for-the-iphone/

Note, this is NOT to test iPhone Apps... but rather, to test websites. I know I could just use a browser, but I was hoping for something with a bit more functionality ( specific to the touch interface ) that I could test some web pages on.

I've seen the beta project here: http://labs.blackbaud.com/NetCommunity/article?artid=662

Is this the best option at the moment? The article was from last year, that's why I ask.

Comment: Don't want to come off snarky, but: You might be better off buying an iPod Touch. It has WiFi so you can browse with it.

Comment: I have one. However, I want something I can do local development on, without having to publish a url or connect to my computer or an IP. I'm looking for convenience, here.

Comment: Perfectly understandable, that.

Comment: @Armstrongest can you consider switching selected answers? Turns out iphonetester.com no longer exists.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add additional information to this post:

found another one for both iphone and ipad: http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/downloads/detail?name=iBBDemo2.air&can=4&q=

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all online, without a simulator:

http://iphonetester.com/

Keep in mind, it's not a *real* test on an iPhone, but if you use it with Safari or Chrome for Windows, you'll come really close to how it'll look on an iPhone.

UPDATE: iphonetester.com no longer exists.

Comment: Excellent. Works as advertised. If I can add too... I found www.ipadpeek.com for the iPad.

Comment: unfortunately, if you type in localhost or some ip into the address bar it goes to google... :-(

Comment: localhost sites work fine for me. This is great for development testing before beta testing on a real phone. I was previously using browserstack, but its not free and its so slow. This is much much better for a fast dev experience. Thank you!

Comment: further testing... K2xL is correct, it doesn't always work with localhost. BUT... if you put the url you want to browse to in as a query param in your actual browser, it works every time... e.g. http://iphonetester.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A10002%2FMyPage#

Comment: Note: this site no longer exists

Comment: The domain was removed. Maybe the answer should be updated.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome now has the ability to "Toggle Device Mode" by clicking the Phone icon in Dev Tools.  This gives you a more touch-specific interface than just using the browser, allows you to throttle data, etc...

[image: phone icon location in chrome dev tools]

From here, you can choose the device:

[image: device selector]

Comment: This only does resolution and touch interface. When you need to get into the knit and grit of the actual OS and how it reads your code the usefulness subsides.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew, agreed.  This question seemed like he didn't care about all of that; rather, he only cared about testing websites in a browser that had touch events.

Answer (score 2):

That's the best I found: http://iphone4simulator.com/

Comment: First page I tested was rendered differently than the real iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial successor to iBBDemo2 that's available for $40 - http://www.electricplum.com/studio.aspx

Comment: There's also an OSS successor to iBBDemo2, called iBBDemo3, which can be found at https://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo3/